# Где вытаскивают БД со штрафами ПДД

Tags: api, rest

Возможно кто-нибудь знает, откуда приложения по оплате штрафов ПДД берут всю информацию о штрафах? И как там работает их оплата. Может быть, есть какое-нибудь официальное REST API для работы вот со всем этим, просто часто вижу подобные приложения, и необходимо узнать через что и как они работают, а реверс-инжирингом заниматься не очень хочется, с учетом того, что код наверняка обфусцирован.

Comment: Например тут http://www.gibdd.ru/check/fines/

Comment: @Visman А как это реализовать, скажем, через Retrofit? Просто я не очень разбираюсь в принципе работы сайтов, но по сути, там же не отправляется http запрос, так ведь?

Comment: Запрос отправляется. Там при заполнении формы сначала вызывается капча и при ее правильном вводе отправляется запрос. Все это на javascript/jquery. Открывайте в браузере инструменты разработчика, запускайте отладчик и смотрите выполняемый код.